# vee-validate error message don't have the field name

Tags: vee-validate

I am trying to get a hand of vee-validate 3. A lot has changed on version 3.
Problem is the error messages do not have the specific field name. Below is the code that i have in a laravel blade file:

```
<validation-provider rules="email" v-slot="{ errors }">
<input type="text" 
class="input" 
name="email"
v-model="email">
<span>@{{ errors[0] }}</span>
</validation-provider>
```

When i strart typing in the input field, the error message prints inside the span tags, but it does not have the field name, rather a generic 'field', such as below:

`{field} is not valid.`

Anybody knows how to get this working?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it in the docs. All you need to do is add a `name` property to the validation-provider component like below:

```
<validation-provider rules="email" name="...add_input_field_name_here..." v-slot="{ errors }">
```